# Clang compilation works while gcc doesn't for diamond inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, gcc, c++11, clang

I'm not sure if I'm missing something here but it seems that the following code (a similar one can be found into another answer I can no longer find, the question here is different by the way) is compiling [just fine for clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/484b070de0b30987) and [not compiling for gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0bc8cf213265bf29)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class base {
public:
 base(int i) {};

private:
 base(){};
};

class derivedA: virtual public base {
public:
 derivedA(int i) : base(i) {};

protected:
  derivedA() : base(0) {};
};

class derivedB: virtual public base {
public:
 derivedB(int i) : base(i) {};

protected:
  derivedB() : base(0) {};
};

class derivedAB : public derivedA, public derivedB {
public:
 derivedAB(int i) {};
 virtual ~derivedAB() = 0;
};

derivedAB::~derivedAB() {};

class lastDerived : public derivedAB {
public:
    lastDerived() : base(1), derivedAB(0) {};
};

int main(){
        lastDerived obj;
}
```

gcc is reporting

```
main.cpp: In constructor 'derivedAB::derivedAB(int)':
main.cpp:9:2: error: 'base::base()' is private
  base(){};
```

Which one is the correct behavior? I'd say gcc's one but I'm not sure why.

Comment: What `return 0;`? `main` doesn't need a return statement.

Comment: Further discussion: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#257

Comment: Also related: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19249

Comment: In case anyone is wondering VS2013 reports the same error as gcc

Comment: What if later derivedA/derivedB changes and someone add to derivedA and derivedB classes a constructor with side effects? Not very maintenable. That would require to fix derivedAB potentially breaking all code using lastDerived or derivedAB (without compiler errors for that!)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A virtual base class of an abstract class does not need to be initialized in the *mem-initializer-list* of a constructor of that abstract base class.

This is discussed in 12.6.2p8:

> [...]  and the entity is not a virtual base class of an abstract class [...] 
>   [ *Note:* An abstract class (10.4) is never a most derived class, thus its constructors never initialize virtual base classes, therefore the corresponding mem-initializers may be omitted. — *end note* ]

So clang is correct, and gcc is incorrect.  This would be different were `derivedAB` not abstract.

---

This is a new allowance in C++11, since [DR 257](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#257); g++ is correct for C++03.  There is a gcc bug at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19249; perhaps it could do with poking.